# ConversationalRetrievalChain with ConversationBufferMemory "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, langchain

When I run langchain's ConversationalRetrievalChain with ConversationBufferMemory I get an error:

> "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

The problem is in: langchain/chains/conversational_retrieval/base.py:25)
This line: `human = "Human: " + human_s` tries to concat a tuple and a string.

`human_s` is a tuple of this form: `('content', 'question user asked')`
Instead, I would expect `human_s` to be `"question user asked".`

This is the code I've used:

```
embedder = get_embedder()
logger.info("loading vector store from {}".format(vector_store_path))
vector_store = FAISS.load_local(vector_store_path, embeddings=embedder)
llm = get_llm()
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(),
    llm=llm,
    memory=memory, verbose=True
)
while True:
    question = input("You:")
    result = qa_chain({'question': question})
    response = result['answer']
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a known bug in langchain https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3077 solved by updating to latest.